# using __new__ to return object from different classes depending on input

Tags: python, new-operator, return-type

I wanted to override `__new__` function, for a specific class, in such a way that depending on the input passed, it returns an object from a class or from another.

I wrote the following code - which seems to work - but it feels like cheating and I wanted to know if this is the "best" or the "most python-like" way to do:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, x):
        if x == 1:
            a = 0
            self = B.__new__(A, a)
            self.cls = B
        else:
            a = 0
            b = 0
            self = C.__new__(A, a, b)
            self.cls = C
        return self

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__class__ = self.cls

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, a):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.a = a
        return self

    def print_this(self):
        print("self.a is: ", self.a)
        print("class is B")

class C(A):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        return self

    def print_this(self):
        print("self.a is: ", self.a)
        print("self.b is: ", self.b)
        print("class is C")
        

xxx = A(1)
print("xxx.__class__: ", xxx.__class__)
xxx.print_this()

yyy = A(2)
print("yyy.__class__: ", yyy.__class__)
yyy.print_this()
```

it returns the following, which is what I wanted

```
xxx.__class__:  <class '__main__.B'>
self.a is:  0
class is B
yyy.__class__:  <class '__main__.C'>
self.a is:  0
self.b is:  0
class is C
```

Comment: IMO, no, this isn't great. What's the point of `class A`? Why not just use a function to do this?

Comment: Why are you using inheritance? `class A` could simply be a factory function: `def a(x): return B(0) if x==1 else C(0, 0)`. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: I simplified the example - otherwise it would be too long - but the point is that within class A there would be defined several functions (sometimes overridden by classes B and C), so that it made sense to me to create such a class A. but, if it's not a good way, I could do as you propose...

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense if we saw the real example. Of course not all code has to be there.

Comment: use a factory function, not the constructor of A

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's dirty - it's not obvious for a reader that `A()` actually creates instance of another class, if someone change something in `B.__new__` he can break parts he would never expects and could be hard to understand for non-experienced python programmers what is going on here.

What you search for is [factory](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/python/example) design pattern.

```
from enum import Enum

class ClsEnum(Enum):
    B = "B"
    C = "C"

class A:
    pass

def cls_factory(e: ClsEnum) -> A:
    if e == ClsEnum.B:
        return B(0)
    elif e == ClsEnum.C:
        return C(0, 0)
    raise TypeError

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def print_this(self):
        print("self.a is: ", self.a)
        print("class is B")


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def print_this(self):
        print("self.a is: ", self.a)
        print("self.b is: ", self.b)
        print("class is C")
        

xxx = cls_factory(ClsEnum.B)
print("xxx.__class__: ", xxx.__class__)
xxx.print_this()

yyy = cls_factory(ClsEnum.C)
print("yyy.__class__: ", yyy.__class__)
yyy.print_this()
```

This code gives the same output as your version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you kindly provide the full code for my example? I am not clear how I should use it

Comment: @SiMo Sorry for delay, I updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when dealing with a similar scenario, and thought I'd add my approach since it worked well.

IMO there is a valid use case for this approach, and in my case it was when working with an identity map wherein there should be exactly one instance of objects with a given id. Since there can only be one instance, it should be the most specific subclass as the user won't be able to create another instance of it later.

Here's a working, mypy-compliant (Python 3.11) example which illustrates my approach.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Type, Optional
from abc import ABC

class A(ABC):

  # return new instance of either A or appropriate subclass of A
  def __new__(cls: Type[A], arg: Optional[str] = None):

    print(f'A.__new__({cls}, arg={arg})')

    # map arg to subclass (can be based on heuristic inspection of args)
    cls_map = {
      'B': B,
      'C': C
    }

    if arg in cls_map:
      # use more specific class
      cls_new = cls_map[arg]
    else:
      # no subclass required
      cls_new = cls

    if cls is cls_new:
      # already have correct class, create new object
      return object.__new__(cls_new)
    else:
      # invoke correct __new__
      return cls_new.__new__(cls_new, arg)

  def __init__(self, arg: Optional[str] = None):
    print(f'A.__init__({arg})')

# subclasses which can be returned by A()
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
```

The neat thing is that B/C don't need to implement __new__ at all or be aware that there's anything unusual going on in A.__new__. However they *can* implement __new__ and it would still work the same, and they can even call super().__new__ if there was some common handling needed (like my identity map scenario).

Test code:

```
a = A()
assert type(a) is A

b = A('B')
assert type(b) is B

c = A('C')
assert type(c) is C
```

Output:

```
A.__new__(<class '__main__.A'>, arg=None)
A.__init__(None)
A.__new__(<class '__main__.A'>, arg=B)
A.__new__(<class '__main__.B'>, arg=B)
A.__init__(B)
A.__new__(<class '__main__.A'>, arg=C)
A.__new__(<class '__main__.C'>, arg=C)
A.__init__(C)
```

Alternatively you could use a factory function, but then you have to call the factory function everywhere rather than just instantiating the class which IMO is more intuitive. Basically the factory function is wrapped by the constructor itself. You're really not violating any rules by returning a more specific class than the one you asked for -- it's still going to quack like a duck, just maybe a more specific quack.

That said, it's unusual for a class to be aware of which classes subclass it, and this kind of approach is rarely necessary.